# undefined method `expect' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Anonymous:0x000000011ef270>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to run tests for my environment on Ubuntu, but every test is failing with the error:
`undefined method 'expect' for  #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Anonymous:0x000000011ef270>`

The ruby test script I am running:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.color = true
  config.formatter = 'doc'
end

RSpec.describe do
  it 'Ruby version 2.2.3 or greater is installed!' do
    expect(RUBY_VERSION).to be >= "2.2"
  end
  it 'Chrome is installed!' do
    chrome_search = `which google-chrome`
    expect(chrome_search).to_not be_empty, "Chrome isn't installed."
  end
  it 'Heroku Toolbelt is installed!' do
    heroku = `which heroku`
    expect(heroku).to_not be_empty, 'Heroku Toolbelt is not installed.'
  end
  it 'Atom or Sublime Text is installed!' do
    subl_search = `which subl`
    expect(subl_search).to_not be_empty, "Couldn't find either Sublime Text installed on your system."
  end
  it 'Atom or Sublime Text Command Line Tools are installed!' do
    atom = `which atom`
    subl = `which subl`
    expect([ atom , subl ]).to_not satisfy { |s|
      s.all?{|search| search.empty? }
    }, "Your text editor is not configured to be launched from your Command Line."
  end
  it 'DBeaver is installed' do
    dbeaver_search = `dpkg --get-selections | grep dbeaver`
    expect(dbeaver_search).to match(/.?dbeaver.?/), "DBeaver is not installed."
  end
  it 'Postgres is installed!' do
    postgres = `which psql`
    expect(postgres).to_not be_empty, 'Postgres is not installed.'
  end
  it 'MySQL is installed.' do
    mysql = `which mysql`
    expect(mysql).to_not be_empty, "MySQL is not installed"
  end
  it 'Git is installed' do
    git = `which git`
    expect(git).to_not be_empty, "Git is not installed"
  end
end
```

Full Stack Trace.  It seems to be one error with the file causing all of the tests to fail.  I'm not sure what the issue may be.  I'm guessing that I could have rspec installed incorrectly?

```
stevenbuchko:~$ rspec '/home/stevenbuchko/WynCode/env_test.rb' 


  Ruby version 2.2.3 or greater is installed! (FAILED - 1)
  Chrome is installed! (FAILED - 2)
  Heroku Toolbelt is installed! (FAILED - 3)
  Atom or Sublime Text is installed! (FAILED - 4)
  Atom or Sublime Text Command Line Tools are installed! (FAILED - 5)
  DBeaver is installed (FAILED - 6)
  Postgres is installed! (FAILED - 7)
  MySQL is installed. (FAILED - 8)
  Git is installed (FAILED - 9)

Failures:

  1)  Ruby version 2.2.3 or greater is installed!
     Failure/Error: expect(RUBY_VERSION).to be >= "2.2"

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `expect' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Anonymous:0x0000000281f478>
     # ./WynCode/env_test.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2)  Chrome is installed!
     Failure/Error: expect(chrome_search).to_not be_empty, "Chrome isn't installed."

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `expect' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Anonymous:0x0000000281a888>
     # ./WynCode/env_test.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3)  Heroku Toolbelt is installed!
     Failure/Error: expect(heroku).to_not be_empty, 'Heroku Toolbelt is not installed.'

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `expect' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Anonymous:0x00000002818e20>
     # ./WynCode/env_test.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4)  Atom or Sublime Text is installed!
     Failure/Error: expect(subl_search).to_not be_empty, "Couldn't find either Sublime Text installed on your system."

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `expect' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Anonymous:0x000000028139c0>
     # ./WynCode/env_test.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5)  Atom or Sublime Text Command Line Tools are installed!
     Failure/Error:
       expect([ atom , subl ]).to_not satisfy { |s|
         s.all?{|search| search.empty? }
       }, "Your text editor is not configured to be launched from your Command Line."

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `expect' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Anonymous:0x00000002812160>
     # ./WynCode/env_test.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6)  DBeaver is installed
     Failure/Error: expect(dbeaver_search).to match(/.?dbeaver.?/), "DBeaver is not installed."

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `expect' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Anonymous:0x00000002810680>
     # ./WynCode/env_test.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7)  Postgres is installed!
     Failure/Error: expect(postgres).to_not be_empty, 'Postgres is not installed.'

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `expect' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Anonymous:0x0000000280f4b0>
     # ./WynCode/env_test.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  8)  MySQL is installed.
     Failure/Error: expect(mysql).to_not be_empty, "MySQL is not installed"

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `expect' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Anonymous:0x0000000280dcf0>
     # ./WynCode/env_test.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  9)  Git is installed
     Failure/Error: expect(git).to_not be_empty, "Git is not installed"

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `expect' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Anonymous:0x0000000280c0f8>
     # ./WynCode/env_test.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.13526 seconds (files took 0.55814 seconds to load)
9 examples, 9 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./WynCode/env_test.rb:7 #  Ruby version 2.2.3 or greater is installed!
rspec ./WynCode/env_test.rb:10 #  Chrome is installed!
rspec ./WynCode/env_test.rb:14 #  Heroku Toolbelt is installed!
rspec ./WynCode/env_test.rb:18 #  Atom or Sublime Text is installed!
rspec ./WynCode/env_test.rb:22 #  Atom or Sublime Text Command Line Tools are installed!
rspec ./WynCode/env_test.rb:29 #  DBeaver is installed
rspec ./WynCode/env_test.rb:33 #  Postgres is installed!
rspec ./WynCode/env_test.rb:37 #  MySQL is installed.
rspec ./WynCode/env_test.rb:41 #  Git is installed
```

Comment: I copied what you have here into a file named "blah_spec.rb", and then ran "rspec blah_spec.rb", and did not get the same error as you.  How are you invoking rspec?  Also, what version of rspec are you using?

Comment: @SomeGuy I invoked it the same way as you described.  Or are you asking how I installed rspec?  I'm using version 3.4.4 of rspec

Comment: Nope, that's what I was asking.  Weird, I've got the same version of rspec installed and am unable to reproduce the error.  Can you post the full stack dump?

Comment: Added what I think is the full stack dump.  Let me know if that's not what you meant

Comment: Drat.  Was hoping you somehow accidentally included some other code that was causing your failures.  I can't see what would cause this.  I'm unable to duplicate it.  The only thing that I can think of is that your rspec install was botched somehow.  At this point I'd try uninstalling and re-installing it.  If that doesn't work, I got nothing left.

Comment: Do you have an `.rspec` in the root of your project?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth , I'm not sure where to find that.  I'm not testing a project, I'm just testing to make sure my environment is set up correctly.  Does this still apply?

Comment: If you're not in a Rails project (I assumed you were from the tag), then just look in your current directory when you run RSpec. RSpec reads that file, so it's another place where something might be set strangely.

Comment: Ended up uninstalling rspec and installing a different version and that seemed to solve the problem.  Thank you both for the help!